# Unix Help -- Digit extractor from file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm new to UNIX and it would be great if someone can help me.

I have a text file called IMSI.txt which has the following format:

```
A imsins -imsi 1241241
A imsins -imsi 5345
```

etc.. The file follows this pattern.

I need to extract the numbers from this file and put them in another file.
The new file will have the following output:

```
1241241
5345
...
```

That's how far i got, but i can't test it to see if it's working

```
#!/bin/sh
grep [:digit:] IMSI.txt >> IMSINEW.txt
or grep '[0-9]'* IMSI.txt >> IMSINEW.txt
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Consider learning [GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) (aka as `gawk`). It is more appropriate for your task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways:

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' a
1241241
5345
```

`NF` in awk stores the number of fields. Thus, `$NF` represents the last field of line, which is what you want.

```
$ grep -o '[0-9]*$' a
1241241
5345
```

In this case, `-o` prints only the matched part of grep. `[0-9]*$` means a group of digits followed by end of line, so that it matches the last part of the line based on digits.

Or better (thanks konsolebox):

```
$ grep -o '[0-9]\+$' a
1241241
5345
```

You can also reverse the file, get the first field with `cut` and reverse back:

```
$ rev file | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
1241241
5345
```

Comment: Better if `[0-9]\+` I think.

Comment: Thanks @konsolebox ! just edited with that version. Good one :)

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for showing me the `rev` command. Anyway, `cut` can do the work even without reversing the lines.

Answer (score 1):

## Using `cut` command

```
$ cut -f 4 -d " " IMSI.txt 
1241241
5345
```

The command takes the document as lines organized into columns.

`-f 4` .. output just the column number 4 (first column has index 1)

`-d " "` .. use `" "` as delimiter of columns.

This assumes, you use space as delimiter. In case there are tabs or other characters, you have to modify it.

Comment: Good one! In case it is always 4 fields, this is a very good way to solve it. +1 also for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another using `tr`:

```
tr -c -d '0-9\n' < file
```